# how to `combn` every combination of every element of a vector into a single list

Tags: r, list, combn

I failed at searching for how to do this specific transformation.  Does anyone have a smart way to achieve this?  sorry if I missed an obvious answer somewhere.  thanks

```
# start with a single vector
1:3

# achieve this desired structure, containing every combination
# from combn( x , 1 ) thru combn( x , length( x ) )
list(
    1 ,
    2 , 
    3 ,
    c( 1 , 2 ) ,
    c( 1 , 3 ) ,
    c( 2 , 3 ) ,
    c( 1 , 2 , 3 )
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Loop through the sequence of values, get the `combn` of the vector with `m` specified as the sequence values, `split` by 'col', flatten the nested list to a `list` of `vector`s with `do.call(c` and `unname` it

```
unname(do.call(c, lapply(1:3, function(x) {
      x1 <- combn(1:3, x)
      split(x1, col(x1))})))
#[[1]]
#[1] 1

#[[2]]
#[1] 2

#[[3]]
#[1] 3

#[[4]]
#[1] 1 2

#[[5]]
#[1] 1 3

#[[6]]
#[1] 2 3

#[[7]]
#[1] 1 2 3
```

Or as @IceCreamToucan mentioned in the comments

```
do.call(c, lapply(1:3, function(x) combn(1:3, x, simplify = FALSE)))
```

Comment: Nice! You can simplify the function to `function(x) combn(1:3, x, simplify = F)`

Comment: @IceCreamToucan  Thanks, that is so compact.  I forgot the `simplify` argument.

Comment: thanks!  maybe it should be `myfun <- function( w ) do.call(c, lapply(seq(w), function(x) combn(w, x, simplify = FALSE)))` so it works on character vectors?

Comment: @AnthonyDamico Yeah, I think `seq_along(w)` would be slightly faster.  Haven't checked it